# CiviContribute - fee calculation error

Tags: civicontribute

I'm getting the error: 'The sum of fee amount and net amount must be equal to total amount' when I'm trying to manually add a contribution. The calculation is correct.

Any help in resoling it appreciated.

Thanks,
Peta

Answer (score 1):

There are few issues reported against this validation([CRM-21624](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21624)). Can you please try after applying the [patch](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/11485) or you will need to wait for 4.7.31 release.